# Search Power Automate flows for string?

Tags: powerapps, power-automate

Periodically, Power Apps entities are changed.  You create fields.  You remove fields.  Dynamics makes managing this easy and safe.  You can't drop a field which has dependencies.  But Power Automate flows don't make for blocking dependencies.

So, you could break a flow if you drop a field with no known deps.

I figured I'd search Power Automate, but as far as I know there's no way to do that.  I can't search and find whether some field name appears inside a flow short of just visually inspecting them all, right?

I'm guessing the only feasible way is to create a solution with all flows and export it, then search the extracted solution folder.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the m365 flow list and export commands of CLI for Microsoft 365.

Here is an example which accepts using a searchstring:
https://pnp.github.io/cli-microsoft365/sample-scripts/flow/search-flows-for-connection/